# vim what is this character '^A'?

Tags: cookies, vim, vi

I have a cookies file generated by a php script using `curl`, when I open it with `vim` I see this strange character '^A' which has a blue color, I know that '^M' means linebreaks, but what is this one? when i try to insert the string that contains this character into a database it looks weird.
What does this character stands for, and are cookies files allowed to have special characters in them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^M` isn't a line break, it's Ctrl-M (also known as `\r` or Carriage Return, character code 13 / 0x0D).

`^A` is Ctrl-A (character code 1 / 0x01).

You can see this by moving your cursor over the character and pressing `ga`.